# argocd-vault-plugin 'generate' section is failing on me with a weird error

Tags: argocd, argo

argocd-vault-plugin for k8s manifest files are failing with this weird error.

Here is my ConfigManagementPlugin info:

```
  [avp.yaml: |
    apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    kind: ConfigManagementPlugin
    metadata:
      name: argocd-vault-plugin
    spec:
      allowConcurrency: true
      discover:
        find:
          command:
            - sh
            - "-c"
            - "find . -name '*.yaml' | xargs -I {} grep \"<path\\|avp\\.kubernetes\\.io\" {} | grep ."
      generate:
        command:
          - argocd-vault-plugin
          - generate
          - "."
          - "-s"
          - "vault-configuration"
      lockRepo: false][1]
```

And the k8s manifest file is:

```
---
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: argo-sample-test-secret
  annotations:
    avp.kubernetes.io/path: "secret/path/in/vault"
type: Opaque
stringData:
  nginx-password: <password>
---
```

And the error is:

[image]

Comment: In the error (screenshot), it says "Error: secrets "vault-configuration" not found Usage" . This vault-configuration is the secret that holds vault connection (VAULT_NAMESPACE, VAULT_TOKEN & VAULT_ADDR & AVP_TYPE & AVP_AUTH_TYPE) info.